# Can't manage to fill all screen with background

Tags: css, height

On low-height pages I have this problem:
[image]

[Here](http://multiformeingegno.it/riflessioni/copiare-file-da-locale-a-un-server-remoto-shell/)'s the page.

I tried setting an height attribute to body with no luck:

```
body {
    linear-gradient(#E2E2E2, #C8C8C8) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your CSS

```
html { 
  height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
}
```

That should set the body background to the full page height.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
html, body {
   linear-gradient(#E2E2E2, #C8C8C8) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do : `html {background:#c8c8c8;}`
or

```
html {
height:100%;
}
body {
min-height:100%;
margin:0;
background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#e2e2e2,#c8c8c8); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try applying it to the html selector:

```
html {
     linear-gradient(#E2E2E2, #C8C8C8) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: You also could try to get the body to be 100%, using `height` or `min-height`